# What are indicators in c++?

Tags: c++

I know that there are three types of indicators i.e. Error indicator, End-Of-File indicator and Position indicator. I am unclear on what exactly is an indicator.

Comment: viz? position and EOF, that's for files.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as an `indicator` in the C++ language specification.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Yn7miIc. This was a question that I came across in one of the Geeks for Geeks quizzes.

Comment: Never heard of "indicator" @AllenJamesVinoy. I question the quality of this quiz.

Comment: @AllenJamesVinoy yeah... don't rely on it. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: This was likely copy pasted from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio, however, this most probably a synonym for a `flag`, itself a loosely defined term.